# How to keep line breaks in POST message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When i get the content of an email it is formatted with line breaks but when i send it to the API the result is text with no white space.

Is there any way to keep the spacing?

**Edit:**

```
const postNewTask = (taskTitle, taskComment, workerId) => {
  const { projectId, tasklistId } = dataStore();

  const { userEmail, apiKey } = credentialsStore();

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(`${userEmail}:${apiKey}`),
    },
  };

  if (taskComment && workerId) {
    options.payload = JSON.stringify({
      name: taskTitle,
      comment: {
        content: taskComment,
      },
      worker: parseInt(workerId),
    });
  }
```

Comment: How are you generating the POST request?

Comment: I added some code that handles the POST request to the question.

Comment: Ok, so `JSON.stringify` is not going to keep line breaks when it turns it into a string.  It will convert them to `\n`.  The backend parser will/should be smart enough to conver those back to line breaks when it gets the data.

Comment: Is there anything i can do with it myself or is it something the backend developer should look into?

Comment: Decoding it from JSON to an actual object is a backend concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. I just had to use `taskComment.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')` and the API knew what to do from there.

**Final working code:**

```
const postNewTask = (taskTitle, taskComment, workerId) => {
  const { projectId, tasklistId } = dataStore();

  const { userEmail, apiKey } = credentialsStore();

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(`${userEmail}:${apiKey}`),
    },
  };

  if (taskComment && workerId) {
    options.payload = JSON.stringify({
      name: taskTitle,
      comment: {
        content: taskComment.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>'),
      },
      worker: parseInt(workerId),
    });
```